# detector circuit sequence

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop

How can I solve this exercise?
Design a circuit with 2 input X,Y and 1 output Z, that be able to identify the following sequence of inputs:
00,10,00,10.
The output Z must assume the logical value 1 when it detects the sequence shown and return to 0 at the first variation of any one of the inputs X,Y.
I have no idea how to get started. 
Thank to all!

Answer (score 0):

You can use design a Finite State Machine using conventional digital logic design techniques. The states might be something like "Waiting for Input", "Received 00", "Received 00 followed by 10".

Alternatively you can use a Data Path approach. You could conceivably solve this problem using a 2-bit FIFO buffer with 4 entries, four 2-bit comparators and a four input AND gate for example. This approach would be more prone to "glitches" in the output however as the output could change in arbitrary ways during transitions.

Comment: Adding a (suitably clocked) register after the output would eliminate any glitches.

Comment: We have not yet studied Finite state machine so i can not use it.How can I realize circuit?I thought I would use 4 flip-flop D cascade forming a shift register,but I don't know how to continue.If you can get a draft of the circuit I'll be gratefull.